# How to automate incoming emails with Power Platform to notify and visualize tabular information with PowerApps?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, excel-online, power-query

I am trying to automate the incoming mail with Power Automate so when a mail arrives with a specific subject I extract the data and save it in an excel file. Power Apps would have this excel as a data source and would show the changes in table format.

The body of the email would look something like this:

> ETA: 02/03 06:00 (CET),
>
> Information
>
> Location: xxx
>
> Identification: xxx
>
> Service: xxx
>
> Order
>
> ETA: 02/03 16:00 (CET)
>
> Other information
>
> Concept: xxx
>
> Errors: xxx

I have this flow: (forgive me for the Spanish of the settings I couldn't changed)
[image: flow]

With this details:
[image: flow details]

On the excel where the data is saved, I transformed the body column with power query to structure the categories by columns:
[image: power query]

I saved this excel in SharePoint and I did the power query in the desktop to upload it again in SharePoint.

The problem I have is that it seems that the query is not updated when new data is entered and the following error message appears when I open the excel online:

[image: error1]

And when I try to update manually from excel online in the queries section:
[image: error2]

It is possible that I am working badly with power query because it's not prepared for this type of automation but I would like to work in this environment.

Later, my idea would be that power apps notify the user with the application when a new email has come (with power automate, it notifies the user in desktop or mobile OUT of the application) and reflects the changes internally in a table or something similar (with a pop up INSIDE the application).

I am thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: Do you have to use excel as your data source? If this is being uploaded to SharePoint any way then you can potentially store the data in a list to achieve the same result. It would remove the complexity of an excel data source which seems to be causing you issues here.

Comment: it's an option but I thougth in a excel because I need to transform the data to get the body of email in a table. With the same headers of the first photo

Comment: You can also go to the PowerApps forum to post for help:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Community/ct-p/PowerApps1